# Nodejs With WinSCP Hello World For Testing

Tags: node.js, winscp

I need a little help to start
I am still Entry level with Node.JS
I am trying to Launch Hello world Project into Server
Here is Steps I did
Creating Hello World Project
[image]

Second Step Cop and Paste The Project into The root of the Server
[image]

Third Step I opened this command console so I can Ask it to Start The server
it is called ( Open Session in PuTTY )

First thing I noticed that the IP here is changed , I don't know why ?

that is not the same IP I am accessing

and Last Step when i command to run the server
it debug (Hello the app is listening )
but comes with the Error
[image]
so please I need help , Thanks alot

Comment: Please edit your question to include properly-formatted text (including code, output, errors, etc), not images of text. This [meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/272109) lists many reasons why this is important.

Comment: Your server might be using port 3000 for something else, you could try changing it. The reason the IP changed is that its showing you the public IP of your ubuntu server, not just localhost. I think you need to do a lot more research into this first

Comment: As other have mentioned, you more then likely need to proxy the request to port 3000. Usually you would have an nginx server infront to proxy request back to port 3000 or wha ever port you are running on

Comment: ok , how to know which port i have to use ?